# .net xAPI not working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've downloaded the .NET xAPI from here: https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanAPILibraryCSharp

When I test the code in console mode I am able to make a connection with both my local server and public lrs: http://tincanapi.com/public-lrs/

However, when I run that same code from Unity, I can only make a connection with my local server, I can no longer connect with the public lrs or any other remote server for that matter, I keep getting "no internet connection" and nothing else.

Any ideas on what this could be??

Answer (score 0):

Currently and if i m right, running dlls compiled with .NET frameworks > 3.5 on unity3d can be a problem. Considering tin can is newly released... Maybe your problem is related?

If you create the dll yourself, be sure to focus on .Net framework 3.5